# CMake multi config generator on multi platform

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, multiplatform

I am working on a project that uses CMake to generate an multi-platform based C++ projects that need to be compiled in both Windows and Linux platforms. In the Windows based projects, I am interested in generating MSVC based solutions that have these four profiles configurations: (Debug, Release, RelWithDebInfo and MinSizeRel).

Please notice that I set some variables (FLAGS_COMPILE_DEBUG, DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG, LINKER_OPTIONS_DEBUG, FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE, DEFS_COMPILE_RELEASE and LINKER_OPTIONS_RELEASE) containing all the specific flags for each Debug and Release based solutions configurations profiles.

```cmake
set(FLAGS_COMPILE_DEBUG "/MTd /Od /Zi /RTC1 /Zc:wchar_t /GS /WX")
set(DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG "-D_DEBUG")
set(LINKER_OPTIONS_DEBUG "/WX")

set(FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE "/Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /GF /Zc:wchar_t /MT /WX")
set(DEFS_COMPILE_RELEASE "-D_NDEBUG")
set(LINKER_OPTIONS_RELEASE "/WX")

# Each one VS profile configurations
add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>)
add_definitions($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>)
add_link_options($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_DEBUG}>)

add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:Release>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>)
remove_definitions($<$<CONFIG:Release>:${DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>)
add_definitions($<$<CONFIG:Release>:${DEFS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>)
add_link_options($<$<CONFIG:Release>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_RELEASE}>)

add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>)
add_definitions($<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>)
add_link_options($<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_DEBUG}>)

add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>)
remove_definitions($<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>)
add_definitions($<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${DEFS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>)
add_link_options($<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_RELEASE}>)
```

However, I noticed that I am not getting the desired effect for each Debug and Release based solutions configurations profiles. What is the correct way to use the CMake generator expressions in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_definitions()` and `remove_definitions()` don't support generator expressions. You want `add_compile_definitions()`.

```cmake
set(FLAGS_COMPILE_DEBUG /MTd /Od /Zi /RTC1 /Zc:wchar_t /GS /WX)
set(DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG -D_DEBUG)
set(LINKER_OPTIONS_DEBUG /WX)

set(FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE /Ox /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /GF /Zc:wchar_t /MT /WX)
set(DEFS_COMPILE_RELEASE -D_NDEBUG)
set(LINKER_OPTIONS_RELEASE /WX)

add_compile_options(
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${FLAGS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>"
)
add_compile_definitions(
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${DEFS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${DEFS_COMPILE_DEBUG}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${DEFS_COMPILE_RELEASE}>"
)
add_link_options(
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_DEBUG}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_RELEASE}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_DEBUG}>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${LINKER_OPTIONS_RELEASE}>"
)
```